# Getting values from catalog_eav_attributes table

Tags: magento2

How i can get value of field which is located in catalog_eav_attributes table?
Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->attributeRepository->get('attribute')->getField()`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following code.

```
  <?php
namespace Jesadiya\AttributeId\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;

class GetAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
    ) {         $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    public function getAttributeId()
    {
        $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get(Product::ENTITY, 'sku');
        return $attribute->getAttributeId();
    }
}
```